# Registration forms not submitting - What Permissions needed

Tags: permissions

Is there a specific Permissions setting we need to turn on for forms to be submitted by anonymous users registering for event?

Error Message:
Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Mandatory fields (first name and last name, OR email address) are missing from this form.

[image: Testing the default Profile Registration Form as an Anonymous user]

Using CiviCRM 5.70 for WordPress

The form works fine When I am signed into WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Tried several tests to resolve the issue. Checked all Anonymous Roles to YES, not this problem. Turned off all WordPress Plugins, not this problem. Changed theme, BINGO!

There was a conflict with one of the JQuery/Lightbox type page overlay option within our theme that cause the forms not to submit. Disabling that option fixed the issue.

The overlay window was loading a separate page and somehow it was loading the Registration form too, doubling up the Registration form!

So, Theme conflict in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the profile you added either does not include First and Last name or Email, which are required fields for events, or you didn't fill out all those items on the form. Do you have a screenshot of the page or a link you can give us?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the screenshot of the form error after clicking Register with the fields filled out.

Comment: I have set CiviEvent: register for events to YES for all.

Comment: Ah, those are added, but required fields. So if you don't fill them out, the form can't be submitted.

Comment: Yea, I see it isn't recognizing any input - not even the Captcha. I haven't used Wordpress with Civi, so I don't know the permissions over there. On my Drupal sites, it by default is set up for anonymous users to be able to input into forms.